# How to properly redirect to the same page in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Here's a simplified code-behind:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int ProductId { get; set; }

public Product Product { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Product = ProductService.Get(ProductId)
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
   if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       retrun Redirect("/login");
   }
   // Add product to user favorite list
   // Then how to redirect properly to the same page?
   // return Redirect("/product") is not working
   // Calling OnGet() does not work
}
```

And here's the corresponding simplified Razor Page:

```
@page "/product/{id}"
@model Product

<div>
    @Model.Title
</div>
```

I'm stuck at properly redirecting user. If I don't return `IActionResult` then my `Redirect("/login")` does not work and I get null reference exception for `@Model.Title`.

If I use `IActionResult` then my `Redirect("/login")` works, but after user logins and adds product to favorites, my code on returning user to the same page fails and `OneGet` does not get called.

Comment: Note: to prevent redirection attacks use LocalRedirect() when detecting a user is not authenticated and you redirect to the login page. LocalRedirect("/login") makes sure you use a local path and protects you against tampering with the querystring return url parameter

Answer (score 4):

In Razor you would use RedirectToPage()

Suppose the class is named IndexModel

```
public class IndexModel: PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
       if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           return Redirect("/login");
       }
       // Add product to user favorite list
       // Then how to redirect properly to the same page?
       // return Redirect("/product") is not working
       // Calling OnGet() does not work

       return RedirectToPage("Index");
   }
}
```

note: you misspelled `return`. Is says `retrun` in you code

**update**
You want to follow the PRG model: after a **P**ost you **R**edirect to a **G**et

to pass parameters back to the OnGet action doe this:

```
public void OnGet(int productId)
{
    Product = ProductService.Get(productId)
}
```

and in your view:

```
@page "/product/{productId}"
```

and in the OnPost

```
return RedirectToPage("Index", new { productId = ProductId});
```

Comment: Thank you @Roger. But this means that I lose all of the query string and route data. How can I keep all the URL? I mean if I could write `RedirectToTheSamePage()` then I wouldn't worry about all URL stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Roger. I think your answer has finally shed light on something that has been bothering me for a long time. I have never heard of PRG model. I have been using return Page(); this whole time, and now I'm thinking that the only time you'd normally return page is for exceptions. I'm going to do further reading on PRG model now.

Answer (score 0):

One can access the page address and query string from `Request` object:

```
var myAddress = Request.Path.Value + Request.QueryString.Value;
return new LocalRedirectResult(myAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int ProductId { get; set; }

public Product Product { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Product = ProductService.Get(ProductId);
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
   if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       return Redirect("/login");
   }
   else
   {
       return Page();
   }
}
```

Try return Page(); so that it refreshes the page you are currently on. Just keep in mind that you will need to reload your Product on the OnPost() call.